# check::assert_parameters for dynamic parameter input

Tags: c++11, argc

I have a simple `assert_parameters` check for argument count. It goes something like this:

`check::assert_parameters(argc, {"arg1", "arg2"});`

Now, I want to add some optional parameters. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You might be looking for [`boost::program_options`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/program_options.html) or similar.

Comment: didn't know this was boost